# java FX VBox layout

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to understand layouts in javafx and I don't understand, why this code doesn't work:

```
public class AppWindow extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Car Race");
    VBox root = new VBox();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

    // menu construction not required for minimal code example

    SubScene layer0 = new SubScene(root, 0, 0);

    ((VBox) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(menuBar, layer0);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I've located the problem in the usage of subscene (without it it works well).

For the question to be complete I include list of all the runtime errors:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: VBox@1537c6b[styleClass=root]is already set as root of another scene or subScene
    at javafx.scene.SubScene$1.invalidated(SubScene.java:255)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.SubScene.setRoot(SubScene.java:213)
    at javafx.scene.SubScene.<init>(SubScene.java:154)
    at javafx.scene.SubScene.<init>(SubScene.java:115)
    at carRace.AppWindow.start(AppWindow.java:45)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
```

I couldn't figure the answer out from the tutorials I had found.

Comment: You're trying to make `root` the root of the subscene, and then you're adding the subscene to `root`... So `root` is contained in the subscene, which is contained in `root`, which is contained in the subscene... etc. (The exception actually occurs because your try to add `root` both to the scene and to the subscene: it can't be a memeber of both.

Comment: Thank you, I see the problem now. Unfortunately I don't understand, how to do it right. I would like to have a window with a menubar at the top and subscene in the rest of this window.

Comment: Why do you need a subscene?

Comment: My idea is to have two transparent layers (first above second) and draw into these layers separately. I thought about solving this problem with two subscenes, but if there is a better way, I will be really glad to find out.

Comment: I don't really know how to help, tbh, because your code doesn't really bear much resemblance to what you describe wanting to do. If you want a menu bar at the top and everything else below, just use a `VBox`, put the menu bar in first and then some kind of pane that contains everything else. For the layers, which is really a completely different question, a `StackPane` is probably what you need. Have you read the [layout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102)?

Comment: I've read the tutorial, but I don't follow all of the ideas. I understand, how to add the menu and StackPane into the VBox, but I don't know, how to make them show in the window (primaryStage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want the subscene to take up part of the scene, and menubar for the rest, so it makes sense to put them both in a VBox, no problem there as long as subscene is accepted as a node to the VBox (I haven't used subscenes before so I wouldn't know).

However, as one of the commentators mentioned, you're putting the VBox, in the subscene, you're putting the whole layout inside a part of the layout. You want to base the subscene on some element that is going to be inside it, not around it.

The obvious choice is to base the subscene on a new Pane, and you could go from there adding all your elements to that Pane.